# Changing status bar light state while running

Tags: android, kotlin, android-theme, android-statusbar

In my app, my splash screen and content have considerably different backgrounds - the splash screen is a darker, uniform colour that requires the default light status bar icons (white icons on a darker background), whereas my content blends the white wallpaper all the way behind the status bar, thereby requiring the dark status bar icons.

This would be solved by using two separate styles, one with `android:windowLightStatusBar` set to true, the other set to false.

However no matter what I do, I can't get this property to change the actual drawing of the status bar. If I start the app with dark status bar icons, I get dark icons all the way, if I choose light status bar icons, I get those.

My app uses a single activity architecture, and I use a custom layout inflater extension method that looks like this:

```kotlin
fun <B : ViewDataBinding> BaseFragment<*, B>.bind(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    @LayoutRes layout: Int,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    @StyleRes style: Int? = null,
    afterBind: () -> Unit = {}
): B =
    DataBindingUtil.inflate<B>(activity!!.getInflater(style), layout, container, false).also {
        if(style != null) activity?.setTheme(style).also { Timber.d("Theme set to ${activity?.resources?.getResourceEntryName(style)}") }
        this.binding = it
        binding.setVariable(BR.viewModel, viewModel)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        afterBind()
    }

fun Context.getInflater(@StyleRes style: Int? = null): LayoutInflater =
    if(style == null)
        LayoutInflater.from(this)
    else
        LayoutInflater.from(this).changeTheme(style)

fun LayoutInflater.changeTheme(@StyleRes style: Int): LayoutInflater = cloneInContext(ContextThemeWrapper(context, style))
```

This `bind` method is used in the `BaseFragment` class, so that I can define my fragments with specific layouts, and have the appropriate ViewModel injected as well, like this:

```kotlin
abstract class BaseFragment<VM : BaseViewModel, B : ViewDataBinding>(vmClass: KClass<VM>, @LayoutRes protected val layout: Int) :
    Fragment(), KoinComponent {
    internal open lateinit var binding: B
    internal open val viewModel: VM by viewModelByClass(vmClass)

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) =
        bind(inflater, layout, container).root
}
```

```kotlin
class SplashFragment :
    BaseFragment<SplashViewModel, FragmentSplashBinding>(
        SplashViewModel::class,
        R.layout.fragment_splash
    ) { }
```

I'm not sure if it's my architecture that's screwing up the status bar change, or if changing the `android:windowLightStatusBar` property is not supported once the app is running.